# Error: TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, init, super

I am an absolutely Python beginner and don't understand the problem of the following lines.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, x):
        print("Base")
        self.x = x

class A(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__(1)
        print("A")
class B(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__(2)
        print("B")

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()
        print("C")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = C()
```

I think super calls looking from C init in the following order: A-B-Base-Base or am I wrong?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Try `print(C.__mro__)`

Comment: When I leave out the super in class B it still does not work.

Comment: That's not the problem. A calls B, and B does not take any arguments in its init.

Comment: Oh I got it. What an embarrassing mistake ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
class A(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__() #Remove this 1
        print("A")
```

I hope it may help you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When answering a question, it’s always great to add some explanation so the OP can learn something from your code.

Comment: @trotta Ok I will take care of this.

Comment: @user11779270 you have really taken great care of this :D